# How to correct retrieve $(object).css(“margin”) and apply this value in .animate() in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery API written what .css() return String. This String have view like `value` without quotes.
If I'll put `$(object).css(“margin”)` in my code like this:
`condition: this != object`

```
$(this).animate({
width: "toggle",
margin: $(object).css("margin"),
padding: ($(object).css("padding"))
}, time, "linear");
```

"Chrome" work out perfectly, but "IE 11" and last "Edge" work out incorrect.
If I'll add to `$(object).css(“margin”)` quotes, all browser work identically.
How identically, You can see in code below.

Eventually I need code which independent of content. How to fix it ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       var time = 200;
       var delay = time + 100;

       $(".icon-language").click(function() {
         slide($(".rightBlockMenu i"), $(this), time);
         $(".hidden").delay(delay).animate({
           width: "show"
         }, time, "linear");
       });
       
       $(".icon-search-1").click(function () {
        slide($(".rightBlockMenu i"), $(this), time);
      });

    $(".icon-user-o").click(function () {
        slide($(".rightBlockMenu i"), $(this), time);
    });

    $(".icon-basket").click(function () {
        slide($(".rightBlockMenu i"), $(this), time);
    });
})

function slide(selector, object, time) {
       if (selector.not(object).css("display") != "none") {
         selector.not(object).animate({
           width: "hide",
           margin: "0px -1px",
           padding: "9px 0px"
         }, time, "linear");
         $(object).animate({
           margin: "0"
         }, time).addClass("active_i");
       }
       if (selector.not(object).css("display") == "none") {
         selector.each(function (){
           if ($(this).is(selector.last())) {
             $(this).animate({
               width: "show",
               margin: "0 0 0 6px",
               padding: "\"" + $(object).css("padding") + "\""
             }, time, "linear");
             $(this).removeClass("active_i");
           } else {
             $(this).animate({
               width: "show",
               margin: "0 6px",
               padding: "9px 18px"
             }, time, "linear", function() {
               if ($(this).is(selector.first())) {
                 $(this).css("margin-left", "0");
               }
             });
             $(this).removeClass("active_i");
           }
         });
     }
     }
```

```css
.header_top {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.rightBlock {
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.rightBlockMenu {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
  font-size: 2.7em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rightBlockMenu i:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.rightBlockMenu i:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.rightBlockMenu i:hover {
  color: hsla(0, 70%, 45%, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rightBlockMenu i {
  padding: 9px 18px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
  display: inline-block;
}

.active_i {
  color: hsla(0, 70%, 45%, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header_top">
  <div class="rightBlock">
    
    <div class="rightBlockMenu">
      <i class="icon-language">aaa</i>
      <i class="icon-search-1" >bbb</i>
      <i class="icon-user-o" >ccc</i>
      <i class="icon-basket" >ddd</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on Firefox, Chrome and Edge and it seemed fine. Maybe clarify more what you are trying to achieve. In any case, your code seems a needlessly complicated.

Find below a shorter version of your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var time = 200;
  var delay = time + 100;

  $(".rightBlockMenu i").click(function() {
    var currentElement = jQuery(this);
    var margin = "0 6px";
    var padding = "9px 18px";
    var toggle = "show";

    if (!currentElement.hasClass("active_i")) {
      currentElement.addClass("active_i")
      margin = "0";
      padding = "9px 0";
      toggle = "hide";
    }

    currentElement.siblings().each(function(index, elemenet) {
      jQuery(elemenet).removeClass("active_i").animate({
        width: toggle,
        margin: margin,
        padding: padding
      }, time, "linear", function() {
        // Show element after it was hidden
        if (currentElement.hasClass("icon-language")) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(elemenet).animate({
              width: "show",
              margin: "0 6px",
              padding: "9px 18px"
            });
          }, delay);
        }
        if (toggle == 'show')
          $(".rightBlockMenu i").removeClass("active_i");

      });
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.header_top {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.rightBlock {
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.rightBlockMenu {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
  font-size: 2.7em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.rightBlockMenu i:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.rightBlockMenu i:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.rightBlockMenu i:hover {
  color: hsla(0, 70%, 45%, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rightBlockMenu i {
  padding: 9px 18px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
  display: inline-block;
}
.active_i {
  color: hsla(0, 70%, 45%, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header_top">
  <div class="rightBlock">

    <div class="rightBlockMenu">
      <i class="icon-language">aaa</i>
      <i class="icon-search-1">bbb</i>
      <i class="icon-user-o">ccc</i>
      <i class="icon-basket">ddd</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I want: 1.after click on "aaa" another elements hide. Margin left and right  are "0" (in your example currient element always has ). Add class.  2. after "aaa" will be hidden and after delay, from the left side "aaa" appears new element what was hiding before. Remove class ".active_i" from "aaa" (It does not work in your example)  3. Do not matter how many time I'll be to click on element, this element should work (your example not work like mine).  4. Need retrieve CSS value from element, rather than write.

Comment: Information what will be shown left, depended on the selected element.

Comment: I updated the code to match what you have asked. I could not understand point 4. The elements will be modified by animate function. That means width, margin and padding will be set by animate. Retrieving these elements will return the current value not the original value.